# How to kill a bash process running in the backend with nohup

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script `forever.py` which I want to run all the time in the background (also after that I close the terminal connected to the VM).
I used `nohup python3 forever.py &` and it worked, but the problem is that after some days it crashes (I guess due to memory overflow) and I need to restart it manually again.
To solve this, I did as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/461546/run-a-python-script-in-background-and-restart-it-on-crash), created a `bash.sh` file containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
until python3 forever.py; do
    echo "'forever.py' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." 2>stderr.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

and in the terminal, ran the command:
`nohup bash bash.sh &`

Currently it's running well and I hope the it restart when the program crashes.
My question is: how do I stop the execution of this?
I tried `pkill nohup` but it doesn't work!

Comment: Try `pkill forever` ... ;)

Comment: check the process id using `ps -ef` for bash.sh. use `kill -9 <pid>` to kill it

Comment: Additionally, if you prefer GUI you can use htop to find the process of your script and kill it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to investigate more about `pkill` command [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill):

```
 pkill -9 -x "forever.py"
```